# Getting "Request unsuccessful. Incapsula incident ID: 1220001110238789559-263723949970693063" while scraping website

Tags: scala, web-scraping, jsoup

I'm trying to scrape website using scala scraper.

**Code:**

```
  val document = JsoupBrowser().get("https://esos.nv.gov/NotarySearchOnline/NotarySearchExternal")
  println(document)
```

But it is giving Incapsula error:

```
<html style="height:100%">
 <head>
  <meta name="ROBOTS" content="NOINDEX, NOFOLLOW">
  <meta name="format-detection" content="telephone=no">
  <meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1.0">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge,chrome=1">
  <script type="text/javascript" src="/_Incapsula_Resource?SWJIYLWA=719d34d31c8e3a6e6fffd425f7e032f3"></script>
  <script src="/bukd-fairers-stayld-his-do-you-she-beth-not-betr" async></script>
 </head>
 <body style="margin:0px;height:100%">
  <iframe id="main-iframe" src="/_Incapsula_Resource?SWUDNSAI=31&amp;xinfo=7-59020918-0%200NNN%20RT%281689249168226%20790%29%20q%280%20-1%20-1%205%29%20r%280%20-1%29%20B12%2811%2c1337794%2c0%29%20U24&amp;incident_id=1220001110238789559-263723949970693063&amp;edet=12&amp;cinfo=0b000000&amp;rpinfo=0&amp;cts=MC1%2bbffyCFI5wK%2bnKF5heCJ8mhMBzBg%2bUp1uiaJLs7YcyEY9lFttNsgaGx7ZImGK&amp;mth=GET" frameborder="0" width="100%" height="100%" marginheight="0px" marginwidth="0px">
Request unsuccessful. Incapsula incident ID: 1220001110238789559-263723949970693063</iframe>
     </body>
    </html>
```

Few days ago, scraping of this site was working fine with same code but now it's is giving above error.

I've tried to scrape it using VPN but still error is same. How can I surpass this error?

Comment: Don't scrape websites!

Answer (score 4):

If you go to the [url returned by the iframe](https://esos.nv.gov/_Incapsula_Resource?SWUDNSAI=31&xinfo=7-59020918-0%200NNN%20RT%281689249168226%20790%29%20q%280%20-1%20-1%205%29%20r%280%20-1%29%20B12%2811%2c1337794%2c0%29%20U24&incident_id=1220001110238789559-263723949970693063&edet=12&cinfo=0b000000&rpinfo=0&cts=MC1%2bbffyCFI5wK%2bnKF5heCJ8mhMBzBg%2bUp1uiaJLs7YcyEY9lFttNsgaGx7ZImGK&mth=GET) you will see the following message

[image]

I guess it's pretty clear. The site have a security layer that is blocking your request. They don't want automated traffic in their web, and if they detect some anomaly they can block you. Not sure if the page offers an API.